# How do I list files when changing directories using tab completion in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, cd, windows-shell

With UNIX command `cd`, when you press tab to complete a file/dir name and there are multiple options, it does an `ls`.

How can I get this behavior in command prompt with `cd`? When you tab complete with `cd` on Windows, it tries all of the matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike in the Bash Shell, Windows requires you press Tab multiple times to cycle through available options — it won’t just show you them all in a list.

If however you want this behaviour you can get it by installing something like
[Clink](http://mridgers.github.io/clink/)

Answer (score -2):

I think you were searching for [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310530), you have to activate it in registry, `completionchar`

Comment: Isn't that just the char for selecting the next match?

Comment: I didn't get you

Comment: That article just talks about changing the character which selects the next match. I'm talking about listing all the matches instead of just selecting the next one.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: In any case please do not post link only answers. You should quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but I'm banned from asking questions,  this does not help me

Comment: @Farzad64 Poor answers won't help you get out of the ban ...

Comment: @Farzad64 I said this in your meta question, submitting answers, won't result in your ability to submit questions to be restored.  The lack of explicit instructions, lack of formatting for the registry key, and the lack of quoting the relevant information from the support article resulted in the vote I issued.  Feel free to blame me, or the community, instead of just improving the answer though (I fully expect you not to improve this answer and just complain about the vote I issued)

Comment: thank you , but there is no way to change this comment to remove the negative votes